How to compute a normal in circle vs rectangle collision to push them apart?
I have a 2D circle, defined from:
c = circle(position = (x,y), radius = r)
I also have a 2D rectangle defined from
r = rectangle(position = (x,y), width = w, height = h)
These elements can both move and rotate in the game.
With these parameters I have a function that detects collision:
Bool circleRectCollsion(c, r)
When a collision have occurred, how to find the normal vector of the rectangle? Such that I can move both the rectangle and the circle out of each other upon collision.

Assuming the rectangle is axis-aligned (not rotated) I believe the simplest solution is to calculate the point on the rectangle that is closest to the center of the circle, then derive the normal from that. Pseudocode:
var boxLeft = r.position.x
var boxRight = boxLeft + r.width
var boxBottom = r.position.y
var boxTop = boxBottom + r.height

var circleX = c.position.x
var circleY = c.position.y

// clamp defined as clamp(input, min, max)
var closestX = clamp(circleX, boxLeft, boxRight)
var closestY = clamp(circleY, boxBottom, boxTop)

var edgePointX = closestX
var edgePointY = closestY

// This part is only necessary if the circle can be inside the rectangle.
// If the circle cannot be inside the rectangle, you can leave
// edgePointX and edgePointY as closestX and closestY.
//
// Note that the order of if-statements is arbitrary, if you prefer separation 
// along a specific axis (say, left-right in a side-scroller) then 
// check that axis first since it will have "priority".
var separationLeft = abs(closestX - boxLeft)
var separationRight = abs(closestX - boxRight)
var separationBottom = abs(closestY - boxBottom)
var separationTop = abs(closestY - boxTop)
var minimumSeparation = min(separationLeft, separationRight, separationBottom, separationTop)

if minimumSeparation == separationLeft:
    edgePointX = boxLeft
    edgePointY = circleY
elif minimumSeparation == separationRight:
    edgePointX = boxRight
    edgePointY = circleY
elif minimumSeparation == separationTop:
    edgePointX = circleX
    edgePointY = boxTop
else:
    edgePointX = circleX
    edgePointY = boxBottom

// Now that we have the closest point along the boxes edge to the 
// center of the circle, we can use that to calculate normal & separation.

var separationAxis = c.position - (edgePointX, edgePointY)
if circleX == closestX && circleY == closestY:
    // The circle is actually inside the rectangle, invert separation axis
    // so it points out of the rectangle instead of in.
    separationAxis = -separationAxis
    
if length(separationAxis) > c.radius:
    return false // No collision

// Collision
var normal = normalized(separationAxis)
return true 

If you need a better guess on which direction to separate the shapes, like in a physics simulation you probably don't want to arbitrarily pick a side, you can store the previous position of the shape(s) and then pick the side closest to the previous position, but the chances of the shape being equally close to two sides is low enough for it to be considered a rare edge-case in my opinion.
